# Is `scan` parameter enabled during scroll in elastic4s?

Tags: scala, scroll, elasticsearch, elastic4s

[Here (at the end of table)](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s#syntax) example about using [scrolls](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) in [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) but I can not see any API to set [scan](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan) parameter. Is it enabled by default or should be used with some hooks?

**By the way**

Or `scan` parameter is enabled by default during `scrolling` in elasticsearch?

Comment: Did my answer satisfy you. If so you should mark it as accepted thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the `scan` parameter when you do the initial search, so:

```
client.execute {
  search in "index" / "type" query <somequery> searchType SearchType.Scan scroll "1m"
}
```

Then later

```
client.execute {
  search scroll <id> keepAlive "1m"
}
```

(Taken from 1.5.x releases of elastic4s)

Comment: In "search scroll" request keepAlive timeout should be specified too, or else response won't contain scrollId for next query.

Comment: how do you fetch the data afterwards ?